# Finding type of model's field in django

Tags: python, django

I have a model like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField("User", verbose_name=u"user", null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    monthly_income = models.ForeignKey(MonthlyIncome, verbose_name=u"Monthly Income", null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    car = models.ManyToManyField(Car, verbose_name=u"Car?", null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

If user changes his profile,these changes saved to another table(UpdateLog). In view I make a query from UpdateLog and if item is in Updatelog, select box would be disable. Because disabled selectboxes doesn't send any data to server, I'm adding the disabled field's value with`request.POST.copy()` as follow view:

in view:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    post_values = request.POST.copy()
    query = UpdateLog.objects.filter(user=request.user.id)
    for a in query:
        field = a.filed_name
        try:
            sd = eval("profile.%s.id"%field) 
            post_values.update({field: u"%s"%sd})
        except AttributeError:
            print field
```

The problem is: `sd = eval("profile.%s.id"%field)` is only works for ForeignKey data. I have to separate `sd` for foreignkey and manytomany fields. How can I recognize type of model's fields in view?

Comment: Have you tried using `getattr(profile, field).id`?

Comment: @RikPoggi's suggestion would be a great improvement over `eval`, please consider it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
from django.db import models
field_name = a.field_name
field = getattr(profile, field_name)
if isinstance(field, models.Model):
    # It's a model object
    # (accessing a foreign key returns a model object)
elif isinstance(field, models.manager.Manager):
    # It's a manager object
    # (accessing a many to many field returns a ManyRelatedManager)
else:
    raise ValueError("Unexpected field type")
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider looking at Django's model options (eg, the `Meta` class) for a more general solution.

```
from django.db import models

model_fields = dict((f.name, f) for f in MyModel._meta.fields)
test_field = field_dict[field_name]
if isinstance(test_field, models.OneToOneField):
    #it's a one to one field!
elif isinstance(test_field, models.ManyToManyField):
    #it's a one to one field!
elif isinstance(test_field, models.IntegerField):
    #it's an integer field!
#...
```

One of the benefits of this approach, outside of generality, is that it doesn't require any database access- it just inspects the schema specified by your model definitions.